# Set the cookie so that it is recognized in users

Tags: php, cookies

I have 3 directories in my website and I am trying to set cookies.

```
web/account/  -- dir 1
web/users/    -- dir 2
```

If I set a cookie in account, it is not recognized in users. How to set the cookie so that it is recognized in users?

Comment: Cookies don't care about directories on your server; they care about URLs. What are the URLs that set the cookies, and how are you setting them?

Comment: Show how you set cookies

Comment: i am testing on local machine. The URLS localhost/web/account/  and localhost/web/users/

Comment: i am using the following code to set the cookies  setcookie("id", $Accid, time()+3600)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `path` argument to `setcookie`, which lets you set the directory that the cookie applies to. By default it's the same directory as the URL of the current script.

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expire, '/');
```

will set a cookie that applies to all directories in your website.